# MacOS, insecure files/directory (zsh compinit)

Tags: macos, shell, security, zsh, zshrc

My shell tells me the following:

```
❯ compaudit
There are insecure files:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
```

I tried fixing this using `$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew` and `$ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew` but that didnt help.
The only other solution I have found was to add `ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true` into my ~./zshrc file. But isnt that just a workaround to ignore the problem?

Comment: Is `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew` an actual file, or a symlink to a file elsewhere? On my machine, it's a (755) symlink to a file with 644 permissions.

Comment: It is a symlink to this file `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew` I ran this but the rights arent changing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:
The file that was making problems (`/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew`) was linking to another file (`/usr/local/Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew`).

So I ran these 2 commands and I was fine:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew
$ sudo chown -R root:staff /usr/local/Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew
```

Answer (score -1):

Change directory (`cd`) into

```
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
```

and then run

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The current working directory shouldn't matter, since you haven't used any relative paths in the command.